# Play 2 sounds one after another in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two sounds

```
  say_1() { //music
    this.audio.src = './sound1.wav'; 
    this.audio.load();
    // auto-start
    this.audio.play();
  }
 say_2() { //speech
    this.audio.src = './sound2.wav';
    this.audio.load();
    // auto-start
    this.audio.play();
  }
```

And I would like to make method `play_all();` which plays one sound after another

```
play_all () {
this.say_1();
this.say_2();
}
```

So, I would like to play as first my music and after that the speech, 
but in my method it plays just second wav and I guess it's because I have this method

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    // destroy audio here
    if (this.audio) {
      this.audio.pause();
      this.audio = null;
    }
  }
```

I need this method, because if I leave page ( go to the next page via router ) music from previous page still plays.

How could I modify my method, so it would play both sound one after another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the audio is being played asynchronously. It means this `play()` method does not wait until the playback has finished.

In order to play these sounds one after another you have to start playing your second file when `ended` event happened.

The most naive solution could look like this:

```
 say_1() { //music
    this.audio.src = './sound1.wav'; 

    // whenever playback ends call the next function
    this.audio.onended = () => {
        this.audio.onended = null;
        this.say_2();
    }

    this.audio.load();
    this.audio.play();
 }

 say_2() { //speech
    this.audio.src = './sound2.wav';
    this.audio.load();
    this.audio.play();
 }
```

Then instead of `playAll()` you could just invoke the `say_1()` method.

You could also extract this into a AudioPlayerService somehow like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class AudioPlayerService {

    playbackEndedSource = new Subject<string>();
    playbackEnded$ = this.playbackEndedSource.asObservable();

    constructor() {
        // this.audio initialization
        this.audio.addEventListener('ended', () => this.playbackEndedSource.next());

    }

    play(path: string): void {
        this.audio.src = path;
        this.audio.load();
        this.audio.play();
    }

}
```

Then you could do it like this

```
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private player: AudioPlayerService) {}

    playAll() {

        const subscription = player.playbackEnded$
            .subscribe(() => {
                player.play('audio2.wav');
                // to prevent it from playing over and over again
                subscription.unsubscribe();
            });
        player.play('audio1.wav');

    }
}
```